# How to port a tf.Session to a tf.train.MonitoredSession call while allowing graph modifications

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

The code I'm working on is [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/blob/master/tftrt/examples/object_detection/object_detection.py).
The code uses tf.session call to take in a graph for object detection tasks.  [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/blob/526f3650a550d6ffcceddfd73d112391080066ad/tftrt/examples/object_detection/object_detection.py#L593-L676)
My aim here is to profile this code for Nvidia GPUs using the nvtx-plugins-tf to analyze the time taken for different ops. [Link to docs](https://nvtx-plugins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates/api.html#session-hooks)

The plugin library provides a function hook for a tf.train.MonitoredSession as given in their example code [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvtx-plugins/blob/a5d47ba6cb0548f2a6c15814d409a14aca4d33f8/examples/tf_session_example.py#L19-L95).
The code linked above uses tf.session along with a tf.config and when I try to modify the tf.session call to a tf.train.MonitoredSession call, I can't get my code to work and it fails with an error that graph can't be modified. I went through the tensorflow APIs and it turns out that tf.session doesn't support hook callbacks and tf.train.MonitoredSession doesn't support tf_config as a function argument.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/mayroy13/Mayank/Mayank/test/tensorrt/tftrt/examples/object_detection/test.py", line 105, in <module>
    test(args.test_config_path)
  File "/home/mayroy13/Mayank/Mayank/test/tensorrt/tftrt/examples/object_detection/test.py", line 81, in test
    **test_config['benchmark_config'])
  File "/home/mayroy13/Mayank/Mayank/test/tensorrt/tftrt/examples/object_detection/object_detection.py", line 608, in benchmark_model
    tf.import_graph_def(frozen_graph, name='')
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 443, in import_graph_def
    _ProcessNewOps(graph)
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 236, in _ProcessNewOps
    for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3751, in _add_new_tf_operations
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3751, in <listcomp>
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3640, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "/home/mayroy13/anaconda3/envs/trt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3225, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Any directions to go in would be appreciated. If there are ways in tensorflow to use hooks in conjunction with tf.session, that will also work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Reason might be is `MonitoredTrainingSession` is finalizing(frozen) the graph, you might require to initialize the graph on loop, you can use the function to create new graph on top of loop.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.Graph().as_default()
```